# bash if conditions as loop

Tags: bash, filenames, md5sum

Hi I want to create a bash file, where i define multiple files (the number is not set) and the script checks if a md5 hash for each file exist, and creates one if not?
I am stuck with the if loop, how can I define a loop with variable length as a if condition?

```
COMPARE_FILES=("/folder/file1" "/folder2/file2" "file3" ... "/folderN/fileN")

for i in "${COMPARE_FILES[@]}"
do

    base=${i%%.*}                # does not work?
    file=${##*/}                 # works as expected

    if [ ! -f $COMPARE_DIR/compare/$base.md5 ]; then

        rsync $COMPARE_LOC/"$i" $COMPARE_DIR/compare/       #works as expected
        md5sum $COMPARE_LOC/$file > $COMPARE_DIR/$base.md5
        rm $COMPARE_DIR/compare/$file                        #does not work

    fi
done
```

I am not able to extract the filename and the base name from the array in the loop, can someone help me perhaps?

Comment: ok i figured the file name out, but i can't get the base to work?

Comment: See my post below.  Edited so now shows you show you should get the basename from a filepath, then split the extension from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the basename from a filepath, use `basename`:

```
$ i="/file/path/filename.ext"
$ base=$(basename $i)
$ echo $base
filename.ext
```

Then you can get the filename without extension as you were doing:

```
$ fnam=${base%.*}
$ echo $fnam
filename
```

Or the extension:

```
$ extn=${base#*.}
$ echo $extn
ext
```

Comment: ok thanks i wrote it new for stack overflow and forgot somethings :) but that was not the problem, the problem lies with extracting the base name and the file name, I always get the folder too